# Change styling of flat QPushButton hover state (without using style sheets)

Tags: qt, hover, pyqt, qpushbutton, qtstylesheets

Flat `QPushButtons` have no indication of mouse hovering. Is there a way to set the styling for the flat button hover state so that it matches the style of the normal button hover state (or something similar)?

[image: QPushButton types]

I don't want to use style sheets if it means deviating away from the default look or having to design the button styles from scratch.

Answer (score 7):

One way of doing it is deriving `QPushButton`:

pushbutton.h:

```
#ifndef PUSHBUTTON_H
#define PUSHBUTTON_H

#include <QPushButton>

class PushButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PushButton(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    bool event(QEvent * event);

};

#endif // PUSHBUTTON_H
```

pushbutton.cpp:

```
#include "pushbutton.h"

#include <QEvent>

PushButton::PushButton(QWidget *parent) :
    QPushButton(parent)
{
    setFlat(true);
}

bool PushButton::event(QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::HoverEnter)
    {
        setFlat(false);
    }

    if(event->type() == QEvent::HoverLeave)
    {
        setFlat(true);
    }

    return QPushButton::event(event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Qt way" is to implement your own `QProxyStyle` or even `QStyle`. It's much more efficient in compare with style sheets. Inside Qt, stylesheets are automatically converted to corresponding `QProxyStyle` objects.

But implementing your own `QStyle` is harder than using QSS.

Comment: You can't achieve what he is looking for with just `QSS`.

Comment: @JacobKrieg rly? Btw, I'm not speaking about QSS at all.

Comment: rly? `But implementing your own QStyle is harder, then using QSS`

Comment: @JacobKrieg rly, because this can be done with QSS simply. You need to set mouse tracking to `QPushButton` or use `QToolButton` instead.